# Can a gentile volunteer to perform prohibited actions on behalf of a Jew on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, gentiles

My mom grew up in Williamsburg, Brooklyn, and then moved to Long Island, and in both places, she was quite happy to serve as a *Shabbos Goy* (gentile who does things for Jews on the Sabbath that would be forbidden for them to do). (I think she made a quarter a week, which translated to a huge pile of candy in the 1950's). Since I joined this site, I have been led to believe that technically, most of what she did - turning lights, heat, stoves and ovens, etc, on and off - would be a violation of the law according to the most strict interpretations anyway, because asking someone to do forbidden things is equivalent to doing those things yourself.

But I am wondering if it would be permissible for a gentile to *volunteer* to serve as a *Shabbos Goy*. By "volunteer", I mean offering to do the job(s) of one's own free will, whether or not compensation is involved.

Does it make a difference if the gentile volunteers?

Comment: You should check out the answer here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61924/759 in order to understand the issues at play and perhaps adjust your question based on your new understanding. (note the glossary term used there: [melocha](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/610/759)).

Comment: @DoubleAA - I was basing the question on this: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43299/why-is-asking-a-non-jew-to-turn-on-electric-lights-considered-amira-lnochri

Comment: These laws are complicated, and there are various exceptions, but it's generally prohibited for a Jew to have a non-Jew perform activities on Shabbat (whether for pay or not) that would be forbidden for the Jew to perform. While there are a number of reasons for this rabbinic restriction, note that none of them are ultimately based in the notion that non-Jews are required to observe the laws of Shabbat. In fact, as the Bible characterizes Shabbat as an intimate covenant between God and the Jews (Exod. 31:13,16,17), it would be inappropriate for a non-Jew to follow all the Shabbat observances.

Comment: ...I mention this just to preempt the notion that Jews who do this are somehow seeking to pass the sin onto a non-Jew while still getting the convenience of skirting Shabbat restrictions. As I alluded to above, it is not biblically forbidden for a Jew to have a non-Jew work for him on Shabbat, but there is a prophetic-level restriction against telling a non-Jew on Shabbat to work for you (based on [Isaiah 58:13](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1058.htm#13)), and even benefiting from such work or arranging the work in advance prior to Shabbat is generally rabbinically prohibited.

Comment: @Fred That's the last thing I would have thought.  I was actually under the impression that the prohibition on Shabbos goyim was partially about trying to prevent the goyim from unwittingly doing something they shouldn't.  But as you just told me, that is not the case.

Comment: @WadCheber I didn't necessarily think you thought that, but I've seen people advance that theory so often that I thought it was worth addressing.

Comment: Hurray for your mom! They serve a very important purpose for us, as you can tell.

Comment: @DanF - She and my dad are responsible for teaching me to respect people's beliefs, and treat others as equals. They took me to Passover Seder a few times, and encouraged me to learn about other people's religions and cultures. My mom also used to know how to speak a little Yiddish, so when I stayed up too late, I was told to "Machen nacht und geh schlaffen". They are very decent human beings, and I totally lucked out in the parent lottery.  But when she was a Shabbos goy, I think her motivation was primarily candy-related.

Comment: @DanF - For a little girl, being paid a relatively large amount of money for doing something as simple as flipping a light switch or turning an oven or thermostat on was an amazing deal.  She probably thought she was getting away with highway robbery.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short if it is forbidden for you, for the gentile to do it for you, it is forbidden even if he volunteered (if he did it for a Jew).

A few laws on this subject in the order they were codified

Introduction

The prohibition for having a gentile do a forbidden work for a Jew on shabos is Rabbinic ([this was from shulchan ariuch harav 306.5](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh2/1/306/5.htm))  and the Rabbi's made a few exemptions to their decree in the decree itself

[325 regarding a gentile that does work for a Jew](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh2/1/307/index.htm).6,7,12

> ו
>
> כל דבר שאסור לעשות בשבת מן הדין אסור לומר לנכרי אפילו מבעוד יום לעשותו בשבת אפילו אינו צריך לדבר זה עד לאחר השבת כגון שאומר לו קודם השבת לשכור לו פועלים בשבת שיעשו לו מלאכה אחר השבת אבל דבר שאינו אלא חומרא בעלמא לישראל עצמו יכול לומר לנכרי בשבת לעשותו:

My unprofessional translation

> 6 everything that is forbidden to do on shabos by law, it is forbidden to tell a gentile even before shabos (for him) to do it on shabos, for example to hire workers (this is a Rabbinic prohibition) on shabos for them to do the work after shabos, but something that is only a stringency for the Jew himself (he) can tell the gentile on shabos to do it
>
> ז
>
> כל דבר שאסור לומר לנכרי לעשותו בשבת אסור אפילו לרמוז לו לעשותו והוא הדין שאסור לומר לו איזה ציווי לעשות דבר המותר בענין שיבין מתוך כך שיעשה מלאכה בשבת כגון לומר לנכרי שיקנח חוטמו כדי שיבין שיסיר הפחם שבראש הנר שהרי זה כמצווהו להסיר הפחם אלא שהוא ברמז ואפילו אם הנכרי בא מעצמו להסיר הפחם בלא רמיזת הישראל צריך למחות בידו אם עושה בשביל הישראל כיון שהנר הוא של הישראל כמו שנתבאר בסי' רע"ו. אבל מותר לומר לנכרי איזה ציווי שיבין ממנו לעשות מלאכה אחר השבת או לרמוז לו מלאכה לעשותה אחר השבת שלא נאסר אלא דיבור בלבד שנאמר ודבר דבר. ואם אינו אומר לו שום ציווי אלא שאומר לפניו איזה דבר שמבין ממנו לעשות מלאכה בשבת הרי זה מותר כגון נכרי שהביא אגרת חתומה או קשורה שאין הישראל יכול לפותחה ולקוראה יכול לומר להנכרי איני יכול לקרותה כל זמן שאינה פתוחה והנכרי פותחה מעצמו שהרי אינו אומר לו שום ציווי אפילו ברמז אלא שהנכרי מבין מעצמו שצריך לעשות כן (ולדעת עצמו הוא עושה להשלים פעולתו בשליחות אגרת זו ולכך אין צריך למחות בידו):
>
> 7 everything that is forbidden to say to a gentile for him to do on shabos, it is even forbidden to hint it to him...
>
> even when the gentile by himself comes (for example) to remove the coal without a hint (of) the Jew he needs to protest against this if he (the gentile ) is doing it for the Jew sing the lamp belongs to the Jew as explained in chapter 276 (if it did not belong to the Jew then he does not need to protest)
>
> But it is permitted to tell the gentile a command (to do something permitted for a Jew as a hint so) that he will understand form it to do a work (that is forbidden on shabos for a Jew) **after** shabos or to hint it...
>
> if he does not command he just said somthing that he (the gentile ) will understand himself to do a forbidden work on shabos it is permitted (if the gentile is doing it for himself) for example a gentile that brought a sealed or tied letter that a Jew can not open and read it (the Jew) can say to the gentile I can not read it until it is not open, and then the gentile opens it himself, since he did not give him any command even a hint only that the gentile  understood from himself that he needs to do this [and he (the gentile is doing this for himself, to finnish his (the gentile's) job, to deliver this letter so he (the Jew) does not need to protest against it]
>
> יב
>
> דבר שאינו מלאכה ואינו אסור לעשותו בשבת אלא משום שבות מותר לישראל לומר לנכרי לעשותו בשבת והוא שיהיה שם מקצת חולי אף על פי שאינו כולל את כל הגוף ולא סכנת אבר או לצורך מצוה אומר ישראל לנכרי לעלות באילן בראש השנה כדי להביא משם שופר לתקוע בו או לומר לו שיביא לו חמין בשבת מחצר לחצר שאין ביניהם עירוב (או דרך כרמלית עיין במ"ש סי' שכ"ה) כדי להרחיץ בהם המצטער. ויש אומרים שהוא הדין במקום הפסד לא גזרו על שבות כגון לטלטל ע"י נכרי סחורה מוקצה הנפסדת ע"י גשמים (ואפילו להביאה לבית דרך כרמלית אם אי אפשר בענין אחר) ויש לסמוך על דבריהם במקום הפסד גדול (והוא הדין לצורך גדול אע"פ שלא שייך שם הפסד). וכל זה בדבר שעושה אותו הנכרי בשבת כדרך שהוא עושה בחול אבל דבר שמשנה בעשייתו מדרך החול אף על פי שהוא שבות גמור מותר לעשותו אפילו ע"י ישראל במקום צער כמ"ש בסימן שכ"ח ויש אומרים שהוא הדין במקום הפסד ויש לסמוך על דבריהם במקום הפסד גדול (עיין סימן של"ו):
>
> 12 somthing that is only forbidden to do on Shabbos Rabbinicly, a Jew can tell a gentile  to do it on shabos
>
> if it is for someone a "little sick" even of it (the sickness) does not effect the whole body and it (the sickness) is not threatening to a limb (to loose it)
>
> or for a mitzva (I.e.) a Jew can tell a gentile to clime a tree (a Rabbinic prohibition) on rosh hashono for him go bring from then a shofar for blowing into it, ...
>
> there is an opinion this law applies, that in a place of loss that they (the Rabbis) did not forbid (to tell a gentile ) to do a Rabbinic prohibition, for example to move muktza (Rabbinic prohibition) merchandise that is getting damaged from the rain through a gentile [even if he (will need to do another Rabbinic prohibition on the way) to carry it through a karmulis if it is not possible a different way]
>
> we can really on (this opinion) there words in a place of a **big** loss [same law applies if a **big** need even is no loss]
>
> all of the above (in this sub chapter 12) is if the gentile  is doing it the way he will do it in the weekday but somthing that he does differently for the way of the weekday even if it is an absolute Rabbinic prohibition it is permitted to do it through a Jew (or the Jew himself) in a place of pain and some say that this law applies in the place (case) of loss, and we can really on their words in a place (case) of **big** loss ...

[Chapter 325 regarding a gentile that does work for a jew](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh2/1/325/index.htm)18,19,20

> יח
>
> וכן הדין בכל דבר שיש לחוש בו שמא ירבה בשבילו אם הוא מכירו כגון נכרי שצלה או בישל לעצמו דברים שאין בהם משום בישולי נכרים וכל כיוצא בדבר זה שצריך להרבות בו בשביל שנים יותר מבשביל אחד אבל בדבר שאין לחוש בו שמא ירבה בשבילו כגון שהדליק נר לעצמו או שעשה כבש לירד בו מהספינה שבנר אחד וכבש אחד יספיק לכל אפילו מכירו מותר:
>
> 18 And so is the law (that it is forbidden to use the leftovers of a gentile untill after shabos) in everything that there is to be afraid that maybe he (the gentile ) increased (did more then he himself needed) for him (the Jew) if he (the gentile ) knows him (the Jew) (so it is possible that the gentile will do something extra for the Jew) for example a gentile  that roasted or cooked something for himself (a type of food) that is not forbidden to eat even if it was cooked by a gentile that he will need to add more to cook for 2 then to cook for one (he is doing extra work specifically for the Jew)
>
> but something that we are not afraid that he added for the Jew (when he did it for himself) for example he (the gentile  lit a lamp for himself or built a ramp to come down on from the bought, since one lamp and one ramp if enough for everyone (no additional labor possible to be done by the gentile  for the Jew) even if he (the gentile  knows him (the Jew) it is **permitted**
>
> יט
>
> אע"פ שאינו מכירו אם אומר בפירוש שלצורך ישראל הוא עושה או אפילו אינו אומר כן אם מעשיו מוכיחים שלצורך ישראל הוא עושה כגון שהדליק נר בבית שהישראל בו והלך לו הנכרי ולא נהנה ממנו כלום אסור להשתמש לאורו:
>
> 19 even if he (the gentile) does not know him (the Jew) if he (the gentile) says that for the needs of a Jew he is doing it or even if he does not say it if his actions proof (we can see from his actions) that for the needs of a Jew he is doing it for example to light a lamp in a house were a Jew is and (then) the gentile leaves and he (the gentile) did not derive any benefit from it is forbidden to use its light
>
> כ
>
> אם ליקט נכרי עשבים (לבהמתו) והאכיל (גם) לבהמת ישראל אין צריך למחות בידו ואע"פ שמן הסתם ליקט גם לצורך ישראל אין איסור בליקוט זה כלל כי כל נכרי העושה דבר מעצמו בודאי מתכוין הוא לטובת עצמו שיודע שלא יפסיד כמו שנתבאר בסי' רנ"ב ובלבד שלא יהיו עשבים של הישראל אלא של הנכרי או של הפקר מטעם שנתבאר שם (וגם אין איסור במה שמאכיל לבהמת ישראל מעשבים שליקט בשבילו שאף שאסור לישראל ליהנות ממה שעשה הנכרי בשבילו אע"פ שנתכוין לטובת עצמו כמו שנתבאר שם מכל מקום כאן אין גופו ממש נהנה מזה לא גזרו חכמים אלא אם כן הוא עצמו עומד בפניה כדי שתאכל אבל לא על מה שהנכרי מאכילה כיון שמתכוין בזה לטובת עצמו). במה דברים אמורים כשהנכרי עושה כן דרך מקרה (שאין הדבר ידוע בבירור שליקט גם בשביל ישראל כי שמא ליקטן לעצמו ואח"כ נמלך ליתן לבהמת ישראל) אבל אם רגיל לעשות כן צריך למחות בידו (שכיון שבודאי הוא ליקטן בשבילו גזרו חכמים אף על מה שמאכיל הנכרי מהם לבהמת ישראל):
>
> 20 if a gentile takes grasses [for his animal] and to feed [also] for the Jews animal (the Jew) does not need to protest, even though probably he collected also for the Jew, this collecting is not forbidden at all , since any gentile that does somthing from (by) himself for sour he (the gentile) did if with intention of his own good, becouse he knows that we will not lose (he will be compensated, even if only with a favor) ... But this is only if the grassed did not belong to a Jew but they belonged to the gentile or they were ownerless, [even though a Jew can not benefit from somthing that the gentile does for him, here is different becouse he is not benefiting himself, only his animal is, the Rabbi's did not make there decree in such a case] and this is only if the gentile does this sometimes that it is not absolutely clear that he is collecting also for the Jew's animal, but if this happens often then (the Jew) needs to protest